# Adding an extra fragment to the backstack while navigating with the Navigation component and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, back-stack

In my application I have a restaurants and dishes list. after clicking on restaurants, the application redirects to the restaurant screen, and when you click back, it returns to the search screen, just popBackStack ().
But after selecting a dish, I would like the app to navigate to the dish screen, and on the back button to go to the restaurant with that dish, and then back to the search screen.
**In other words, I just want to know if navigating to a particular fragment you can add an extra fragment between them**, so that when returning back to it first, and then to the starting fragment?
If not, is it possible to achieve this in any other way?

Comment: u don't need to call the popBackStack() on your own, the navigation component does this all on it's own, and the desired outcome you want is the default behavior, so unless you have a a logic error while implementing it shouldn't be a problem, you should post your code for navigation so that i can help you better

Comment: I just want to know if navigating to a particular fragment you can add an extra fragment between them.

Comment: no you cannot, what you can do is override the popUpTo in the nav_graph XML

Comment: my point is, if you do the following, Search>View Restaurant>Click on Dish, then there's no way that if you do click back while on the dish screen that u will return directly to the Search, you will always redirect back to the View Restaurant, unless maybe you added a popBackStack or navigateUp call extra on your own

Comment: unfortunately, by clicking on a dish, you should be redirected directly to the dish screen, skipping the restaurant screen, despite all going back, the restaurant menu should appear

Comment: if it was me designing the logic for this application, this would be a very weird UX decision that will affect the users using your app, HOWEVER this can be solved if you have the restaurant ID for example inside the object of the dish, or you can get the ID by doing an API request with the restaurant name, while both are not recommended you will need the ID for the next step, which is setting the popUpTo for the dish fragment to always pop to the restaurant, and figure out a way to send the ID to the restaurant fragment, bit of a work around and i would not recommend but this might help you

Comment: i would strongly suggest revisiting the Logic of the app in your case, UX is the most important aspect when creating something, if your user feel like the app is broken, that's an instant uninstall

Comment: Can I somehow check what fragment id is "under" the current fragment in the backstack?

Comment: unfortunately this has been a known issue with the navigation component, you can't differentiate between the open fragments but you can get instances of all of them at once.